# Wordpress (Genesis child theme) fs background image hidden by white background in "Home 2" Area

Tags: wordpress, plugins, background-image

I've inherited management of an existing Wordpress site that uses a custom Genesis child theme. I have attempted to set a full screen background image using the "Full Screen BG Image" plugin. However, the Home 2 area, used for a widget displaying latest posts, seems to have an irreversibly opaque background and the background image hides behind it. When I pull that section of the page down, I see the background image peek out from behind at the top. [See It Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXb3Y.png)

I am not a Wordpress expert, and I'm learning as I go. It would be amazing if there were a simple solution that would get our background image to display on our front page.

Thanks in advance, with apologies for my lack of knowledge!

Comment: Can you post the site url? The screenshot doesn't really give us enough to go on

Comment: http://www.snugharborwine.com/ I have a large centered image there for the time being since the fullscreen background isn't working properly.  Have at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solid white background is set by your child theme's `style.css` file like so

```
.home-widgets-2 {
    background-color: #fff;
    ...
}
```

You can just change that background-color statement to `background-color: transparent;` or `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);` where .5 can be anywhere from 0 - 1 and controls the opacity.

You can either edit that in your `style.css` file itself (recommended if it's a child theme you manage/made) or you can add it in the Appearance > Customizer > Custom CSS section like so:

```
.home-widgets-2 {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Using `transparent` makes it hard to read, so I'd suggest using the transparency options like `rgba(255,255,255,.65)`

Comment: @LeaF. - My pleasure! If you wouldn't mind clicking the check mark to mark this answer as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: Done!  Thanks again!